# How to assign mySQL values -> HTML -> PDF (MPDF)

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, pdf

### Following is my code:

### PHP function

```
public function createReport()
    {
        $data = [];
        //load the view and saved it into $html variable
        $html=$this->load->view('forms/reports', $data, true);

        //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
        $pdfFilePath = "Report.pdf";

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');

       //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        //download it.
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");        
    }
```

---

### View HTML code: forms/reports

```
<body>
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><label id="lblTitle"> Testing 1<label> </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;" valign="top" align="right" style="text-align:center;padding:3mm;">
                        <label>App :101</label><br><label>REV : 5</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;">
                        <b>CUSTOMER</b> : <label id="lblDesc1"> Bafna automobiles</label><br />
                        <b>NUMBER</b> : <label id="lblDesc2"> 100100101122</label><br />
                        <b>DESCRIPTION</b> :  <label id="lblDesc3">Single bus </label><br />
                        <b>No</b> :  <label id="lblDesc4">Auto 1 to auto 10</label><br />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
```

---

### Load data from DB

```
 public function loadJobPanels($TestId)
        {
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("auto_job");

            $this->db->where("AutoTestId = ",$TestId); 

            $query = $this->db->get();
            $data['get_Data'] = $query->result();
    }
```

---

How to assign "$data['get_Data']" to my View & send it to $html to pass further to $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
I am able to show data in HTML page (View), however not getting how to pass HTML with data to PDF.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both functions are within the same class. You could pass the data as properties (variable) of the class.

```
Class someClass
{
    private $data = [];

    public function createReport(){
        $data = $this->data;
        ...
    }
    public function loadJobPanels($TestId){
        ...
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

However, you should check if the class variable is set.

Comment: I am able to assign data to my view, now i hv to pass that dynamic page to create PDF. I think you dint get my question.

Comment: @VDS Sorry, I indeed misunderstood your question. Does it work with some simple HTML, like in their examples? Otherwise I would recommend comparing your tag attributes to the supported HTML attributes list.